# Linear Gradient (black) from top to bottom on image with Text on foreground (bottom-left)

Tags: html, css

The linear gradient works with the image but the texts does not appear on the image foreground. Also the gradient should not be on the texts. Where did I go wrong?

Any help will be much appreciated.

```css
.glimage {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url(/assets/img/rests/bangkok.jpg);
  height: 220px;
}

.glimage:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%), url(/assets/img/rests/scenery.jpg);
}
.gltext {
  position:absolute;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="glimage">
    <div class="gltext">
      <h2>Travelling</h2> 
<p>These are texts.</p></div>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing your `z-index`. A high z-index will "pull it closer" to you.

```css
.glimage {
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url(/assets/img/rests/bangkok.jpg);
  height: 220px;
}

.glimage:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%), url(/assets/img/rests/scenery.jpg);
}
.gltext {
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="glimage">
    <div class="gltext">
      <h2>Travelling</h2> 
<p>These are texts.</p></div>

</div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want the texts to be on the image foreground bottom and not outside. So how do I achieve that?

Comment: I've updated the answer. It's what I figured you wanted in the first place but your question was a bit unclear.  Does that meet your needs?

Comment: That's absolutely brilliant. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update your class `.gltext` by adding `z-index:1000`. You can just add `z-index:1` it will also work because you are not using z-index but better to use some large value.
Your updated `.gltext` class would be;

```
.gltext {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

You can learn more about `z-index` from [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. Appreciate it.